# Does training with a more difficult task improve model performance on easier tasks?

Tags: neural-networks

Say I have a time series deep learning model where I am trying to predict whether an event will end tomorrow and I am using binary classification to do this. If I change the target (or add another one) and predict the duration to the end of the event, which I think is a harder task, or if I use multiclass classification to predict whether the event will end tomorrow, in 2 days or in 3 or more days, will this improve the predictions for the next day's (tomorrow's) events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may well do so, but there is no guarantee. You can construct counterexamples where these approaches will not work, and examples where it *will* work, and this very probably holds for *any* such scheme you are thinking about. Whether this works "often enough" in a specific domain is an empirical question.